# MAUI Blazor. Publish iOS. Can not create an IOS archive. Code object is not signed at all

Tags: ios, .net, blazor, maui

The app is working fine on windows, android and with ios hotreload with local connected iPhone.

The app uses sqllite.

I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-app-store?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vs#publish-the-app)  . Now I have connected Mac in cloud and all the apple ids, certificates etc.

When I try to publish a new MAUI Blazor app everything works as expected. But when I try to publish my app I have this error in Archive Manager window after about 5 minutes of execution:

`Can not create an IOS archive..... Process can not be executed on XMA server...... codesign exited with code 1: code object is not signed at all..... In subcomponent..... SQLLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqllite.ios.aotdata.arm64`

I tried to create a new MAUI Blazor app and move my code there step by step. And the magic is that let's say at point A everything worked, then I add some page for example and this error appeares. Then I return my code to point A but the error is still there. Then again I try to create a new MAUI app and it publishes without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was [fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14044).

The problem is that the app bundle contains a Resources directory. Removing this directory makes the app sign correctly.

As a workaround, it seems that setting the Link metadata instead of the LogicalName metadata works:

change this

```
<MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
```

to this

```
<MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" Link="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
```